# asp.net mvc url of anchor's start with "/" is wrong?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, seo

in my Asp.Net MVC web project i always use anchors url as

`<a href="/xxxx"></a>`

which is making my urls working good. output is like below

`<a href="www.mydomain.com/xxxx"></a>` if in host

`<a href="localhost/xxxx"></a>` if in development

I am using Search Engine Optimization Toolkit (http://www.iis.net/download/seotoolkit) for finding errors in my webpage.

What I see in results is "broken hyperlinks". When I looked to the results link that start with "/xxx" is not like "domain.com/xxx" seo toolkit sense url like "domain.com/currentpage/xxx".

What is the problem is in here?

Am I doing wrong with writing links start with "/" ? Is it wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of hardcoding urls I would recommend you using HTML helpers:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("link text", "someAction", "someController") %>
```

This will generate proper relative URLs no matter whether you are running on development or production server inside virtual directories, etc...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you mark your anchors as runat="server" and change / with ~/ in your URLs.

Let ASP.NET resolve your relative paths to absolute ones.

"/" is for specifying that your path starts at the root of your Web Site. That's good in most of the cases, but what happens if your application is nested in some other virtual directory? Your URL would be invalid in this case.

"~/" resolves your path as an absolute path, but of your Web Application, that's you've nested applications, this "magic" will render the full path to the application's folder.

Does it help?

Comment: Instead of making anchors runat="server", you can use the url helper <%=Url.Content("~/xxxx")%> to get the absolute path.